# Use List<>, Array or something else?

Tags: c#

i'm doing some programming exercises from Exercism.io and need some input on how to start on the Grade-School assignment.

The assignment is to add name and grade and receive name from grade index in the form of `List<string>`.

The first tests for the assignments looks like this:

```
[Test]
public void New_school_has_an_empty_roster()
{
    Assert.That(school.Roster, Has.Count.EqualTo(0));
}


[Test]
public void Adding_a_student_adds_them_to_the_roster_for_the_given_grade()
{
    school.Add("Aimee", 2);
    var expected = new List<string> { "Aimee" };
    Assert.That(school.Roster[2], Is.EqualTo(expected));
}
```

I'm not looking for a complete solution but i need some advice on what Roster should be. My thought was that Roster would be a array of List like this:

```
public List<string>[] Roster = new List<string>[];
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't pass the first test because i have to assign a length for the array so count will never be 0. 
I need a push in the right direction on how to solve this.

Comment: An array of lists makes little sense and does not match your code either.  Just a single list is enough, delete the [] brackets.

Comment: Looks like your storing a list of indexed items, with a key and a value. `List<T>` and Arrays only stores a value. To associate items with a key, take a look at [`Dictionary<T,U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If grade is your index then you should use a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` structure. The `int` is the key, in your case grade and the list contains the names of students with that grade.

When you add a grade and student, you check if the dictionary has any value for that grade, if so, then get the value (of type `List<string>`) and add the student name to that list, otherwise create a new list and add the student name.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use an Array of Lists, that would get confiusing. Read into Object Oriented Programming (OOP) and look at the user of Classes.

I would have a class to represent a Person (or in your case a student) somthing like:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Grade {get; set; }
}
```

and store them in a simple List of Students

```
public List<Student> Roster;
```

Another way to look at is a Dictionary so,

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Roster;
```

where each entry is Student name and Grade so:

```
Roster.Add("John Mclain", "A*");
```

You could also look into Enumerations (Enums) to store the grades instead of using Strings.

Comment: I'd agree, but it may be a lesson in data structures only, not necessarily OOP and class, etc.

Comment: Thanx! I agree that a class would be best but this exercise was data structures only.

Comment: I went with Dictionary<int, List<string>> to be able to store multiple names per grade.

Comment: No worries, might have been easier to say :P but i Dict is far better than an array of lists :P

Answer (score 0):

Your list initialisation is wrong, thats why you get error that you have to assign a size for the array. 
This is how you make a list:

```
   public List<string> Roster = new List<string>();
```

But the better way in this case is to create a class Student or use a Dictionary.